# Assembly Resolve in Multi-tenant Application

Tags: .net-assembly, multi-tenant, appdomain, resolve, assemblyresolve

I'm using "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve" in my multi tenant application and in the Assembly Resolve method, I'm planning to resolve the dll based on the current tenant. 
The problem is that Assembly Resolve method always refer to the first request context. I understand that as Assembly Resolve is registered at the AppDomain, it will use the same context that it received during the first call.

**My question is:**
What are other options to resolve the assembly per tenant?
I need to know the tenant context in Assembly Resolve somehow.

I tried to un-register and re-register the `AssemblyResolve` event, but that isn't possible either.